# Write the same data with different file names using single Item writer using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, itemwriter

I have a Spring Batch `FlatFileItemWriter` which writes data to a specific location with a file name(let's say A.txt for example). Now I need the same file to be written with different file name (let's say B.txt) . How can I achieve this with a single item writer? Is it possible?If not are there any alternative solutions?The below is my code

```
 public FlatFileItemWriter<MyRecord> myItemWriter(@Qualifier("myAggregator") LineAggregator<MyRecord> lineAggregator) throws IOException {

    String fileName= this.localTempPath + fileProperties.myLength() + getTime();
    


    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<MyRecord>()
            .name("my_itemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(//path of resource)
            .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
            .encoding(fileProperties.getEncodingMyLength())
            .append(true)
            .lineSeparator("\r\n")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: If you need the exact same contents, why wasting time re-generating them (with an `ItemWriter`)? Instead you should add another step in the enclosing job and simply copy (or hard link) to the first file.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter which writes data to a specific location with a file name(let's say A.txt for example). Now I need the same file to be written with different file name (let's say B.txt) . How can I achieve this with a single item writer? Is it possible?

You can use a [CompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) that delegates to two `FlatFileItemWriter`s (one for each file).

> If not are there any alternative solutions?

As mentioned above, it is possible, but an alternative could be adding a tasklet step that duplicates the file with a different name.